# scroll element out before reaching top

Tags: html, css, scroll, offset, transparent

I am working on a website with a fixed navbar. The navbar has a transparent background and stands in front of a background image for the whole page.

The problem is that I want the following elements to disappear just below the navbar. But instead they are scrolling behind the transparent navbar.

I have found nothing, yet, to to set the following content in the div#scrollwrapper to scroll out at top:124px. Instead is scrolls behind the transparent nav.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <nav></nav>
    <div id="scrollwrapper"></div>
  </div>
<footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
  min-height:100%;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#wrapper:after{
  background-image: url(../img/bg.jpg);
  background-color: #0b0d89;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  content: "";
  opacity: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
 }

.navbar {
  background-color: 
  rgba(11, 13, 137, 0.5600000000000001);
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1020;
 }
```

Comment: There is no such “scrolling out”, what you are dreaming of here does not exist. You need to either apply the scrollbar somewhere else (not on the whole page, but only on a container that starts below your header) - or _give_ the navigation a background, so that the content can be hidden underneath it.

Comment: you would need to use the same background image in your nav and as you scroll the page, you can change the background position of the image in your nav using some js so it matches the movement of the main background - or as your background is fixed then you don't shouldn't need the js bit.  Also why put the background in a pseudo element rather than directly on the div?

Comment: Pete, that is just because I might want to change the opacity of the background image. Maybe not, then it could run in a div.

It's unbelievable that none of such functions exists. Really?

Comment: Can't you wrap them in a div and add a margin top the same height as the navbar?

Comment: No Ali, that does not change the scrolling behavior.